# Missing images in SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

It looks like some images are missing in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just updated the image sources for these - all fixed up.

Comment: Was it also part of the pathing bug? Or something different?

Comment: One of the images are still broken, I don't remember which one.