# The images on the main page of SEDE are not loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I visited the main page of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and noticed that most of the images return a 404:

[image: broken images]

This looks like a similar problem as reported earlier in [Missing images in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277546/missing-images-in-sede) but that covered the site-switch drop down which is working in this case.

I suppose this is related to the content move on the CDN [earlier this week](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/141859797844/partial-outage-postmortem-march-28th-2016).

I repro-ed this in Chrome, FF and Edge, so it is not browser dependent. I'm in Western Europe, probably routing over the AMS-IX, in case CloudFlare is involved.

Notice that following apple-touch-icons.png do load, they are all for the meta sites of:
[Stats](http://cdn.sstatic.net/statsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Academia](http://cdn.sstatic.net/academiameta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Islam](http://cdn.sstatic.net/islammeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Japanse](http://cdn.sstatic.net/jameta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Pets](http://cdn.sstatic.net/petsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Quantative Finance](http://cdn.sstatic.net/quantmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Productivity](http://cdn.sstatic.net/productivitymeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Lego](http://cdn.sstatic.net/bricksmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Portugese](http://cdn.sstatic.net/portuguesemeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
, [Elementary-OS](http://cdn.sstatic.net/elementaryosmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)

#### Can either the paths on SEDE be fixed or the images on the CDN  be restored?

Inspired on [this migration](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/Migrations/053%20-%20Add%20Sites.BadgeIconUrl.sql) I would start with this sql query on the SEDE database to stay inline with the intent:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.[Sites]
 SET BadgeIconUrl = ''//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/'' 
                 + (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''meta.'', TinyName) = 1 
                         THEN SUBSTRING(TinyName, 6, LEN(TinyName) - 5) + ''meta'' 
                         ELSE TinyName END) + ''/img/apple-touch-icon.png''
WHERE Id IN( 
  SELECT Id
    FROM dbo.[Sites]
   WHERE CHARINDEX(''stackexchange.com'', Url) != 0
      OR CHARINDEX(''stackoverflow.com'', Url) != 0
      OR CHARINDEX(''serverfault.com'', Url) != 0
      OR CHARINDEX(''superuser.com'', Url) != 0
      OR CHARINDEX(''stackapps.com'', Url) != 0
      OR CHARINDEX(''askubuntu.com'', Url) != 0
      OR CHARINDEX(''mathoverflow.net'', Url) != 0
)
```

Comment: I can only *partially* reproduce this - I get some of the images (the top 4 of SO, Math, SU, AU load) and some don't.

Comment: Looks like they still move cheese around, and SEDE is left behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like we didn't update the import properly, so it kept updating to the wrong images.

We put in an immediate fix for the images and will fix the import at a later time (likely today).

Comment: Just so I understand: you fix this in your private import scripts, not in the public github repro of the DataExplorer, right?

Comment: @rene - the image URLs are in the DB, not in code.

Comment: That is true but I did point out [this migration](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/Migrations/053%20-%20Add%20Sites.BadgeIconUrl.sql) that is the initial creation and seed of that field.  I'm only trying to prevent the situation where you re-run all migrations later on for what ever reason to find that stuff is broken again .... been there, done that ;)

Comment: The migration was already run - it won't run again (given that the column... exists).